# How to convert Stack based instructions to Register based

Tags: jvm, virtual-machine, instruction-set, dx

This is what I have tested with the dis module in python -

```
>>> def f():
...   a = 1
...   b = 2
...   c = 3
...   a = b + c * a
...   return a + c
...
>>> dis.dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              2 STORE_FAST               0 (a)

  3           4 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
              6 STORE_FAST               1 (b)

  4           8 LOAD_CONST               3 (3)
             10 STORE_FAST               2 (c)

  5          12 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
             14 LOAD_FAST                2 (c)
             16 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             18 BINARY_MULTIPLY
             20 BINARY_ADD
             22 STORE_FAST               0 (a)

  6          24 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             26 LOAD_FAST                2 (c)
             28 BINARY_ADD
             30 RETURN_VALUE
```

Those are instructions for a stack-based virtual machine. Is there any way to convert the above stack-based instructions into register-based instructions provided I have access to unlimited number of registers.

I only know about one tool which does that, we know that JVM is stack based but Dalvik VM is register-based. When we write code in Java, the class files contain stack based instructions and the dx tool converts the stack based instructions to register based instructions so that it can run in the Dalvik VM. So most probably there could be an algorithm somewhere which I have missed.

Also can there be an edge can where the stack could dynamically grow and shrink(which would be decided in runtime) , in that case it would be impossible to convert stack based instructions to register based. However one tool does it.

Can someone point me to the correct direction. Or know any algorithm which can help in this.

Comment: The register-based conversion will place the N most common values into registers, however as you say this limited.

Comment: I said if it has unlimited registers(assumption)

Comment: The translation is trivial: just imagine that each stack slot is a register. A stack-based instruction `BINARY_ADD` executed at stack depth 5 could be translated to a register-based instruction `ADD R4, R5` (or `ADD R4, R4, R5` in case of three-op instruction set).

Comment: I’m confused. Are you asking about the JVM or Python? Or is your question just hypothetical and not about an actual programming problem?

Comment: The output of dis module is just a real-life example of instructions in a stack based virtual machine. JVM and CPython both have stack based vm. Dalvik is register based vm. There is a tool called dx which converts JVM bytecode to dalvik vm bytecodes. I want to know how I can convert stack based instructions to register based. There must be a simple explanation on how to write a program on it. Or probably an algorithm I have missed.

Comment: Well, apangin did already explain it. At least for the JVM, the edge case of dynamically growing stack does not exist. Bytecode is not allowed to do that. So for every instruction, the exact stack layout can be determined in advance and every branch instruction is required to target an instruction with a compatible stack layout (starting with Java 6, the byte code will even contain a declaration of each branch target’s stack layout). Further, each method declares the maximum stack size used by its code. Mapping the implied operands to numerical indices is trivial.

Comment: Ok that did help. Thanks @apangin

Comment: And also @Holger